# htaccess url folder redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to change my url to try to stop it from showing the language folder in the url for example:

change from
www.site.com/en

change to
www.site.com

so I am looking to remove the

> en

from the url but still accessing that directory. This is what I have so far but it does not seem to do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ en=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi friend, I tried this but with no luck it does not seem to do the trick for me, thank you very much for helping. I look forward to other suggestions

Comment: why do you have `RewriteBase /mysite/`? try without it. Do you get any kind of errors?

Comment: I had it there to tell the code where the rewrite base is but I also just removed it and tested it without it but still no difference, it just keeps showing the www.mysite.com/en even when I try to remove it